# Push notification using GCM from my Android App

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am receiving push notification for my android app as per my requirement. But facing a strange problem. If internet is not connected in the mobile and we send push message from third party server, we can't get the notification. **Understood** !!!! But the moment it is connected, it should receive those  notifications which were previously pushed . I am not getting those notifications even though I am connecting internet to my device, which was not connected when the notification was been send . I am facing this problem. What might be the cause??????

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't receive any push notifications if your internet is **turned off**.

You can check the **[lifetime of a message](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#lifetime)**.

### Addition

Try adding this set of codes to the bottom of your *onMessage()*

```
    String message = yourMessage;

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    final String packageName = "your.package.name";
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
        if (appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            if(appProcess.importance != RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                generateNotification(context, message);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=............  Can you help me how much value should I pass to the above time_to_live parameter. This total thing I passing from server side using Asp.net server

Comment: The default timeout is 4 weeks if `time_to_live` is not set. `time_to_live` is how long in seconds the message will live in the Google GCM server. `(e.g.: time_to_live=2419200)` **2419200** is 4 weeks in seconds. So basically your `time_to_live=108` is 1minute and 48seconds in lifetime of the message. `collapse_key` is not needed if you don't want to use `time_to_live`

Comment: long when = System.currentTimeMillis();NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    notificationIntent, 0);notificationManager.notify((int)when, notification);   IS THERE ANYTHING WRONG IN CODING.

Comment: Did you try to log the onMessage?

Comment: protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
  // String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
  String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
  Log.d("Message Received", message);

  // displayMessage(context, message);
  // notifies user
  generateNotification(context, message);
 } This is my onMessage method......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23951/discussion-between-arijit-and-ramyle)